# Apply formula on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, formula, cell-array

I have this formula: `100-[(x-1)/(y-1)]*100`, and I would like to apply it to a cell-type variable `F` with `A rows * 14 columns` in MATLAB, where `x = F(:,14)` and `y = size(F,1)`.

I have been trying to get there by different attempts, this is one example I tried:

```
F(:,15) = cellfun(@minus, 100, ((cell2mat(F(:,14)-1)./size(F,1)) * 100));
```

But it is not working. Could someone help me?

Comment: Not working why? Any errors?

Comment: `cellfun` works on **cell** arrays.  By applying `cell2mat`, you are transforming a `cell` array back into a **matrix**.  As such, the input into `cellfun` is no longer a `cell` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood this correctly, first let me show how to do it the way you described:

```
% a random cell array of 10 rows x 5 columns
% each cell contains one number
F = num2cell(rand(10,5));

% compute formula on 1st column. Result is a numeric vector
out = 100 - ((cell2mat(F(:,1))-1) ./ size(F,1))*100;

% put result back into cell array (by converting into expected format)
F(:,5) = num2cell(out);
```

Now since `F` is a cell array simply containing a scalar number in each of its cells, why don't you just use a regaular **numeric** matrix instead? That way you avoid calling `cell2mat` and `num2cell` back and forth...

Comment: Thank you for the help! F is a cell array but it doesn't contain only scalar numbers, it also has char. strings. My `x` ( your `F(:,1) ) `is a number though! I have been applying `cell2mat` a lot, maybe that's why I also tried it here, but I can try without too!

Comment: Hey! I just tried your formula, it's working perfectly. I don't know I that was your point before, but I don't need to aplly the `F = num2cell(rand(10,5));` it works! really nice :) Thanks

Comment: is there a way to do this without converting to mat, then to cell?

Comment: @DanPowers You can write a loop over the cell elements (either implicit with `cellfun` or an explicit for-loop), however numeric operations like that are better vectorized. Ultimately I think you need to use the right kind of container; if your data/columns is all numeric is you should store it a numeric matrix, rather than a heterogeneous cell array.